# How to declare bits in C?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, literals

I'm trying to do this :

```
uint64_t key = 0110000010110110011001101111101000111111111010001011000110001110;
```

Doesn't work. `GCC` says

> warning: integer constant is too large for its type

Any idea why?

Comment: Why would you expect the C compiler to interpret that as a binary number?  I would suggest [reading the docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html).

Comment: This exact warning will depend on `-std=<dialect>` option, and other warning flags provided.

Comment: Thanks for this RTFM larsks. But I'll try to ELI5 you the real question here : can you declare bits without using hexadecimal. Hopefuly someone clever wrote the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although neither the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) nor the [draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) support binary literals, since you specifically mention `gcc` it has an [extension for binary literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) which says:

> Integer constants can be written as binary constants, consisting of a sequence of ‘0’ and ‘1’ digits, prefixed by ‘0b’ or ‘0B’. This is particularly useful in environments that operate a lot on the bit level (like microcontrollers).

they gives the following example (*[see it live](http://rextester.com/LJH96882)*):

> i = 0b101010;

and it looks like `clang` also support this as [an extension](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) as well (*[see it live](https://godbolt.org/z/lXN05I)*):

> [...]binary literals (for instance, 0b10010) are recognized. Clang supports this feature as an extension in all language modes.

This is not available in standard C++ either until C++14 [[lex.icon]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/lex.icon).

Comment: I wouldn't use it for more than a few bits, as long bit strings become unreadable and error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the leading 0 that's read as a very large octal literal, which is probably not what you want. Amazingly, C doesn't have binary literals.

As an extension, `gcc` supports binary literals with the `0b` prefix, eg, `0b101010`. If you don't want to rely on extensions, hexadecimal is probably the most reasonable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use Hex decimal they are more compact and can represent binary example:

```
0x01 // This is 0001
0x02 // 0010
```

Using binary the way you want is particularly ugly inside someone's code.

Also starting a number with 0 (in your example) will be interpreted as octal.

Comment: this was just for test purpose

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Shafik's answer:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t i = UINT64_C(
        0b0110000010110110011001101111101000111111111010001011000110001110);

    printf("%" PRIX64 "\n", i) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Worked with: `gcc -std=gnu99` - output: `60B666FA3FE8B18E`

Really, embedded systems are much more strict about extensions, particularly if you're unfortunate enough to be required to adhere to standards like [MISRA-C](http://www.misra-c.com/Activities/MISRAC/tabid/160/Default.aspx). Hexadecimal conversion is just the grouping of 4 binary digits to 0x0 -> 0xf.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you exceeded the maximum integer that can be stored in an uint datatype.
Try using an array of boolean type.